# Unable to click the below overlay on Android 12

Tags: android, overlay, foreground-service, android-12

I have an [App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.blue.light.filter.eyecare.nightmode.nightscreens) on the play store. This app basically creates an overlay on top of all the apps with some colors, It works perfectly for anything below Android 12. But, since Android 12 it no longer works. I can still interact with my application, but once minimized I no longer can click on anything or change anything at all. I have to restart the device to close the application.

```
  val params = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY
            else WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE
                    or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                    or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
                    or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
        )
```

This is how I create the overlay on top. I checked the documentation, but could not find any information. I will be grateful if I can get any help and suggestions to fix this issue.

Comment: This is part of the untrusted touch events in Android. Blog post: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/untrusted-touch-events-2c0e0b9c374c

Answer (score 3):

Set alpha to window manager params, its works for me.

**Try below snippet code:**

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 31) 
{
    params.alpha = 0.8f;
}
```

Comment: The value shouldn't be hardcoded. OEMs can change it the exemptions for untrusted touch mention that it is subject to change in future APIs. Instead, you should use  `InputManager.getMaximumObscuringOpacityForTouch()` to retrieve the current value.

Comment: @AbandonedCart - How is it possible to access `getMaximumObscuringOpacityForTouch()`? Seems to be a hidden api, and impossible to call `InputManager.getMaximumObscuringOpacityForTouch()`

`InputManager().maximumObscuringOpacityForTouch` also does not work as InputManager is private init.

Somehow using reflection but I'm unable to manage it thus far.

Comment: @niall8s You're trying to call it as a static. You need a reference to the InputManager.

Comment: @AbandonedCart - how is that possible if InputManager init is private? Can you provide an example please? Using getSystemService or?

Comment: @niall8s The `SystemService.method()` notation is a standard. It *always* implies falling back to a `getSystemService()` reference. Most, if not all, system service classes are private because this is common practice for accessing them.